# Create an opaque UIColor that appears the same as another which is translucent

Tags: cocoa-touch, colors, alpha, uicolor

This color

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:75.0/255.0 
                green:215.0/255.0
                 blue:100.0/255.0 
                alpha:0.5]
```

and this one, with different RGB values and no transparency,

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:165.0/255.0 
                green:235.0/255.0 
                 blue:177.0/255.0 
                alpha:1]
```

look exactly the same on a white background.

How do I go from the first `UIColor` to the second `UIColor`?

Comment: Are you always working in the RGB color space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the answer will rely specifically on knowing the background color. Something like this would work, assuming `backgroundColor` and `sourceColor` are UIColors:

```
float blend(float src, float srcAlpha, float background) {
  return (background + src * srcAlpha) / 2;
}
UIColor *result = [UIColor colorWithRed:blend([sourceColor red], [sourceColor alpha], [backgroundColor red])
                                    green:blend([sourceColor green], [sourceColor alpha], [backgroundColor green])
                                    blue:blend([sourceColor blue], [sourceColor alpha], [backgroundColor blue])
                                    alpha:1.0f];
```

While the numbers aren't equal to your example, this is a reasonable blend function that is generic. Without more examples it's hard to know what the curve of your example is. The blend function you're using appears to use a different ratio for each color component, or perhaps your measurement of the resultant color values are being adjusted by the color profile of your screen.

Comment: Hi, would you mind explaining a bit more on why / how this solves the issue OP experienced (am just curious)? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Sure, most of the other answers didn't actually give a new color. If you have a solid black color at 50% alpha and put it on a white background, you'll be translating 1.0 values of black at 50% alpha to 0.5 values of black with 1.0 alpha. The blend function I gave a sample to above does precisely that. The other answers at the time of me writing mine showed how to take the 1.0 black, and get the 1.0 black out with 1.0 alpha instead of giving the blended color.

Answer (score 0):

NilObject's answer was good, but I ended up using something more specific to my problem.

The base color I wanted different shades from was this:

`cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:75.0/255.0 green:215.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:1];`

Here's my solution:

`cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 - (255-75)*rate/255.0 green:1 - (255-215)*rate/255.0 blue:1 - (255-100)*rate/255.0 alpha:1];`

Where `rate` would replace `alpha`